# Android Dynamic Module Error -2 (MODULE_UNAVAILABLE)

Tags: android, kotlin, dynamic-feature-module, dfm

on last Saturday I already fix the issue in my Dynamic module app.

At first I already make an application file that extend `SplitCompatApplication`. But right now in this afternoon, the error back again, I can't download or install my dynamic module in my Internal App Sharing. But it run perfectly fine in debug with whole APK in run configuration.

Any suggestion why it is happened? I already searching many question about it in Stack Overflow or GitHub. But still no clue.

I already follow the documentation about dynamic module, but still error occurred.

Answer (score 0):

This is really funny. It was not an error on the app, but at Google Play Store.

For you all maybe will encounter this error. Maybe the key on 2022 is, wait for a minutes or more. After you wait, you can download the module.